# Yii2 добавляет ошибку в конец ворд файла в PHPWord

Tags: yii2, phpword

С помощью библиотеки PHPWord создаю и сохраняю файл. Yii2 добавляет в конец файла ошибку:

```
<pre>An Error occurred while handling another error:...
```

Из-за этого при открытии файла появляется ошибка, если вручную убрать ошибку из конца файла через Notepad++, то все работает нормально.
Как сделать чтобы ошибка не записывалась в файл?
Вот мой код:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$section->addText(htmlspecialchars('TEXT'));
$file = 'Наукові публікації ЗНУ.docx';
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='. $file .' ');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$xmlWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$xmlWriter->save("php://output");
```

Comment: http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=30547

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю насколько это правильно, но у меня получилось решить проблему следующим образом.
Вместо того чтобы сразу отправлять файл на загрузку, я сохраняю его на сервере и с помощью `Yii::$app->response->sendFile()` оправляю пользователю.
Вот код:

```
$file = 'Publications.docx';
$xmlWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$xmlWriter->save($file);
$dir = Yii::getAlias('@app/web/'.$file);
Yii::$app->response->sendFile($dir);
```

Может кому-то пригодится.

Comment: только остаётся вопрос с чисткой мусора файлов на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Ну прочитать что написано после "An Error occurred while handling another error:", там развернутый текст ошибки. Найти где она выпадает, и устранить. Используйте дэбаг, что бы эффективнее изучить проблему.
Всего этого недостаточно для конкретного совета. Нужен как минимум текст ошибки и место куда она ссылается.

Comment: Если не сложно, посмотрите на ошибку
<pre>An Error occurred while handling another error:
yii\web\HeadersAlreadySentException: Headers already sent in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\phpoffice\phpword\src\PhpWord\Writer\AbstractWriter.php on line 244. in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php:366<br>
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Response.php(339): yii\web\Response-&gt;sendHeaders()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\ErrorHandler.php(124): yii\web\Response-&gt;send()

Comment: #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\ErrorHandler.php(111): yii\web\ErrorHandler-&gt;renderException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#3 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleException(Object(yii\base\ErrorException))
#4 {main}
Previous exception:
yii\base\ErrorException: Undefined variable: searchModel in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\views\publication\index.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\views\publication\index.php(28): yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleError(8, &#039;Undefined varia...&#039;, &#039;C:\\xampp\\htdocs...&#039;, 28, Array)

Comment: "Headers already sent in " - вот критически важное место в этом сообщении. http-протокол имеет конкретные правила формирования ответа. Сначала должны идти заголовки, потом тело ответа. В коде вопроса вы отправляете три заголовка и получаете ошибку о том, что заголовки уже отправлены. Вам нужно найти где вы отправляете НЕ заголовки до этих заголовков. Это может быть излишне закрытый тег ?> или любой echo, print_r, var_dump, что угодно, что выводит на экран.

Comment: спасибо, буду искать.